# JComboBox remembering other selections

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a JTable and in one column I have a JComboBox for each of the rows. I am dynamically adding rows when I press a button. The selection made in the combobox will determine what calculation is carried out for that particular row. For arguments sake lets say that the options for the combobox are: option 1, option 2, option 3 and option 4.

The issue I am having is as follows:

Say I have added 2 rows and select any option from the combobox for row 1, when I go to make a selection in the combobox for row 2 the same selection is ticked as was made for row 1. There seems to be some kind of memory. How can I disable this, so that the default selection is always -1 (i.e. non of the options selected)? I would like to have complete control over this.

Here is an example snippet of code just considering option 1:

```
String labels[] = {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option4"};
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(labels);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);


        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
        int state = itemEvent.getStateChange();
        ItemSelectable is = itemEvent.getItemSelectable();

        if (selectedString(is) == "Option 1" & state == ItemEvent.SELECTED){


            System.out.println("A");    

        }

        }

        };  

    comboBox.addItemListener(itemListener);
```

Thanks very much for your time and help :)

Comment: sorry code talking about nothing ..., for better help sooner post an SSCCE/ MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable / XxxTableModel in local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use "==" when comparing strings. Instead you should be using the `equals(...)` method:

```
if (someString.equals(anotherString))
    // do something
```

However, that is not the cause of the problem.

You are using the JComboBox incorrectly for a JTable. You should NOT be using a ItemListener (or any listener).

The combo box is just used as an editor for the table. That means when you select a value from the combo box, the `TableModel` of the table is updated. So if you have custom logic based on the selected value you need to override the `setValueAt(...)` method of your `TableModel`.

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
{
    super.setValueAt(value, row, column);

    //  add your custom logic here
}
```

> How can I disable this, so that the default selection is always -1

The value displayed in the combo box is taken from the `TableModel`. So if you set the default value to be null the combo box will not have a selection when you start editing.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples. Keep the tutorial link handy for future reference on Swing basics.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Much appreciated!